# Bad CakePHP webroot for SSL Security (OVH)

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using OVH to host my website. Some people recently asked me to secure the whole CakePHP Website with SSL. Actually, OVH provides a SSL security using their absolute path : https://sslX.ovh.net/~login

So i moved the website in www/sitename directory, to reach it like this :
[HTTPS HOST]/~login/sitename

My problem comes here : all my links are like this :
[HTTPS HOST]/sitename/XX/YY

Instead of 
[HTTPS HOST]/~login/sitename/XX/YY

My question is the following : How can I change the webroot to create good links ?

Thanks much.

Comment: Usually cakephp will work like this out of the box. Can you provide more information: server name, version? By the way are you using the HTML helper or are you hard coding the links?

Comment: My CakePHP version is 1.3.3. I make links using $this->webroot + 'x'; But my webroot is wrong : it doesn't contain ~login/ in the string...